# Tree equality operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, operators, haskell-platform

I'm very very new to Haskell and I'm trying to wrap my head around the syntax (as well as getting used to a declarative language). I've made a tree data type and I wish to be able to compare them using the == operator. Here's what I have:

```
data Tree =
    Leaf
  | Twig
  | Branch Tree Tree Tree
  deriving Show;

instance Eq Tree where
    Leaf == Leaf = True;
    (Branch a b c) == (Branch a1 b1 c1) = a==a1 && b==b1 && c==c1;
```

This seems to work when inputting : `Leaf == Leaf` or `Branch Leaf Leaf Leaf == Branch Leaf Leaf Leaf` but it keeps giving me an error when I add `Twig == Twig = True;`. Also, there is no way to compare `Leaf == Branch Leaf Leaf Leaf`. I tried using `_==_ = False;` but that also gave me an error. I'm lost, any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Still getting errors, specifically :

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Tree.hs, interpreted )

Tree.hs:15:5: parse error on input ‘_’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Tree.hs, interpreted )

Tree.hs:15:3: parse error on input ‘Twig’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The first is after I take out the problematic Twig ==, leaving the _ == _. The second is leaving both in.

Comment: If you post the exact code that is triggering errors, you'll probably get an explanation of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Your code works for me with the things added that you said gave errors, specifically

```
instance Eq Tree where
    Leaf == Leaf = True;
    (Branch a b c) == (Branch a1 b1 c1) = a==a1 && b==b1 && c==c1;
    Twig == Twig = True;
    _ == _ = False;
```

(BTW the `;` at the end of the lines is redundant.)

I suspect you may have an indentation error. Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Also, all of that instance declaration is simply equivalent to changing your `deriving` clause to

```
deriving (Show,Eq)
```

as that is precisely how the default derived `Eq` instance works.

Comment: The Haskell wikibook has a [nice section on indentation and the layout rule](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) that the questioner may find useful. In particular, it walks through converting to and from "one-dimensional" semicolon style.